# MySQL Update based on a query in another table

Tags: mysql

I want to update a table with a query from another table.

I want to get mixed informations from a combination of two tables.
And then update one of the two tables with them.

Here is what I did :

```
UPDATE commande as C,
    (
        SELECT CONCAT (input_hauteur_sous_collecteur, ' x ', input_largeur_hors_tout, ' x ', input_epaisseur, ' - ', input_pas_ailettes) 
        AS 'ligne_sage'
        FROM commande as C, faisceaux_ta as F 
        WHERE C.commande_type_faisceaux = 'TA' 
        AND C.commande_id_faisceaux = F.id 
    ) AS src
SET
    C.ligne_sage = src.ligne_sage
WHERE
    C.commande_type_faisceaux = "TA"
```

/* And I got MySQL running the command and never ending without error notification... */

EDIT : Actually it finally works in more than 5 minutes, the problem is that I have the same values (first line of the SELECT result table) in each lines...

What shall I do to make it work ?
(the SELECT CONCAT subquery is properly working)

Comment: I haven't yet found a need for the CONCAT function, so I'm always suspicious of  queries that use them.

Comment: It is running indefinitely because you have a Cartesian product (Cross join). You should really avoid using Comma based implicit joins and use explicit `JOIN .. ON` syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this because you didn't filter results between tables.  You need to add and filter in the where clause.  Something like (see last line).  I don't have your tables defs :-(

```
    UPDATE commande as C,
        (
            SELECT CONCAT (input_hauteur_sous_collecteur, ' x ', input_largeur_hors_tout, ' x ', input_epaisseur, ' - ', input_pas_ailettes) 
            AS 'ligne_sage'
            FROM commande as C, faisceaux_ta as F 
            WHERE C.commande_type_faisceaux = 'TA' 
            AND C.commande_id_faisceaux = F.id 
        ) AS src
    SET
        C.ligne_sage = src.ligne_sage
    WHERE
        C.commande_type_faisceaux = "TA"

        AND c.commandId = src.commandId
```

Comment: Thanks !! That did it.